# Spark to MongoDB via Mesos

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, cluster-computing, mesos, mesosphere

I am trying to connect Apache Spark to MongoDB using Mesos. Here is my architecture: -

MongoDB: MongoDB Cluster of 2 shards, 1 config server and 1 query server. 
Mesos: 1 Mesos Master, 4 Mesos slaves

Now I have installed Spark on just 1 node. There is not much information available on this out there. I just wanted to pose a few questions: -

As per what I understand, I can connect Spark to MongoDB via mesos. In other words, I end up using MongoDB as a storage layer. Do I really Need Hadoop? Is it mandatory to pull all the data into Hadoop just for Spark to read it?

Here is the reason I am asking this. The Spark Install expects the HADOOP_HOME variable to be set. This seems like very tight coupling !! Most of the posts on the net speak about MongoDB-Hadoop connector. It doesn't make sense if you're forcing me to move everything to hadoop.

Does anyone have an answer?

Regards
Mario

Answer (score 0):

Spark itself takes a dependency on Hadoop and data in HDFS can be used as a datasource.

However, if you use the [Mongo Spark Connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/) you can use MongoDB as a datasource for Spark without going via Hadoop at all.

Comment: Thank you Ross. However, as mentioned above by Youe, Spark expects the HADOOP_HOME variable to be set while installation!! This clearly indicates that its tied to the hip with Hadoop, no matter what they say about Spark being independant.

Answer (score 0):

[Spark-mongo connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/) is good idea, moreover if your are executing Spark in a hadoop cluster you need set HADOOP_HOME.

Check your requeriments and test it ([tutorial](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/the-new-mongodb-connector-for-apache-spark-in-action-building-a-movie-recommendation-engine))

```
Basic working knowledge of MongoDB and Apache Spark. Refer to the MongoDB documentation and Spark documentation.
Running MongoDB instance (version 2.6 or later).
Spark 1.6.x.
Scala 2.10.x if using the mongo-spark-connector_2.10 package
Scala 2.11.x if using the mongo-spark-connector_2.11 package
```

The new MongoDB Connector for Apache Spark provides higher performance, greater ease of use and, access to more advanced Spark functionality than the MongoDB Connector for Hadoop. The following table compares the capabilities of both connectors.

Then you need to configure Spark with mesos:

[Connecting Spark to Mesos](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html)

```
To use Mesos from Spark, you need a Spark binary package available in a place accessible by Mesos, and a Spark driver program configured to connect to Mesos.

Alternatively, you can also install Spark in the same location in all the Mesos slaves, and configure spark.mesos.executor.home (defaults to SPARK_HOME) to point to that location.
```

Comment: No I do not wish to have this Hadoop dependancy. I am talking about Spark going straight to MongoDB via Mesos.