# How to sink streaming data from spark to Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using pyspark to read streaming data from Kafka and then I want to sink that data to mongodb. I have included all the required packages, but it throws the error that
**UnsupportedOperationException: Data source com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource does not support streamed writing**

The following links are not related to my question

[Writing to mongoDB from Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50566592/writing-to-mongodb-from-spark)

[Spark to MongoDB via Mesos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995739/spark-to-mongodb-via-mesos)

Here is the full error stack trace

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/b3ds/kafka-spark.py",
>   line 85, in 
>       .option("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource","mongodb://localhost:27017/twitter.test")\
>   File
>   "/home/b3ds/hdp/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming.py",
>   line 827, in start   File
>   "/home/b3ds/hdp/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1133, in **call**   File
>   "/home/b3ds/hdp/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
>   line 63, in deco   File
>   "/home/b3ds/hdp/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
>   line 319, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling o122.start. :
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source
>   com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource does not support streamed writing
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSink(DataSource.scala:287)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:272)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
>           at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
>           at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
>           at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>           at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>           at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Here is my pyspark code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import json
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import datetime

json_schema = StructType([
  StructField("twitterid", StringType(), True),
  StructField("created_at", StringType(), True),
  StructField("tweet", StringType(), True),
  StructField("screen_name", StringType(), True)
])

def parse_json(df):
    twitterid   = json.loads(df[0])['id']
    created_at  = json.loads(df[0])['created_at']
    tweet       = json.loads(df[0])['text']
    tweet       = json.loads(df[0])['text']
    screen_name = json.loads(df[0])['user']['screen_name']
    return [twitterid, created_at, tweet, screen_name]

def convert_twitter_date(timestamp_str):
    output_ts = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp_str.replace('+0000 ',''), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
    return output_ts

if __name__ == "__main__":

        spark = SparkSession\
                        .builder\
                        .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount")\
                        .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri","mongodb://192.168.1.16:27017/twitter.test")\
                        .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri","mongodb://192.168.1.16:27017/twitter.test")\
                        .getOrCreate()
        events = spark\
                        .readStream\
                        .format("kafka")\
                        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")\
                        .option("subscribe", "twitter")\
                        .load()
        events = events.selectExpr("CAST(value as String)")

        udf_parse_json = udf(parse_json , json_schema)
        udf_convert_twitter_date = udf(convert_twitter_date, TimestampType())
        jsonoutput = events.withColumn("parsed_field", udf_parse_json(struct([events[x] for x in events.columns]))) \
                                        .where(col("parsed_field").isNotNull()) \
                                        .withColumn("created_at", col("parsed_field.created_at")) \
                                        .withColumn("screen_name", col("parsed_field.screen_name")) \
                                        .withColumn("tweet", col("parsed_field.tweet")) \
                                        .withColumn("created_at_ts", udf_convert_twitter_date(col("parsed_field.created_at")))

        windowedCounts = jsonoutput.groupBy(window(jsonoutput.created_at_ts, "1 minutes", "15 seconds"),jsonoutput.screen_name)$

        mongooutput = jsonoutput \
                        .writeStream \
                        .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")\
                        .option("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource","mongodb://localhost:27017/twitter.test")\
                        .start()
        mongooutput.awaitTermination()
```

**I have seen the mongodb documentation which says it supports spark to mongo sink**

https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/streaming/

Comment: Did you get it working? I have similar problem.

Comment: Hi, Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

> I have seen the mongodb documentation which says it supports spark to mongo sink

What documentation claims, is that you can use standard `RDD` API to write each RDD using legacy Streaming (`DStream`) API.

It doesn't suggest that MongoDB supports Structured Streaming, and it doesn't. Since you use PySpark, where [`forEach` writer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach) is not accessible, you'll have to wait, until (if ever) MongoDB package is updated to support streaming operations.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB Spark Connector now supports Apache Spark Structured Streaming.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/structured-streaming/